# How to use RowMeans function combining with agrregate

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I need to get a chart which shows the mean resolution time for a bunch of support requests. I got a data frame with all the requests, every line is a different request, and each column represents a different field like month, priority, group, resolution time and so on...

From that table I would like to get the mean resolution time for every month. I have been trying different ways but I haven't been able so far. I think I am very close right now. This is my code:

```
df_tresolucion <- setNames(aggregate(tabla_tiempos$Ticket,by=list(tabla_tiempos$Metrica),FUN = rowMeans(tabla_tiempos[,10,drop=FALSE])),c("Metrica","Promedio"))
```

**tabla_tiempos** is the data frame I have mentioned before containing all the support requests:

```
Ticket <- c('119237','119239','120598','120600','120612', '120615')
 Metrica <- c('apr 2017','may 2017', 'may 2017','may 2017','jun 2017','jun 2017')
Pais <- c('ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP')Estado <- c('Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed')
Escalado <- c('CEDEX', 'CEDEX', 'TAC','CEDEX','CEDEX','TAC')
Vendor <- c('Cisco','Cisco','Cisco','Juniper','Cisco','Cisco')
Familia <- c('C7600','C7600','MX960','C7600','C7600','MX960')
Severidad <- c('Minor','Minor','Major','Minor','Minor','Major')
SLA <- c('Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA')
tresolucion <- c ('1.73','2.30','26.97','1.73','2.30','26.97')
tabla_tiempos <- data.frame(Ticket,Metrica,Pais,Estado,Vendor,Familia,Severidad,SLA,tresolucion)
```

**$Ticket** is a unique field for each request and **$Metrica** represent the month where the request was opened.The 10th column in the data frame **tabla_tiempos** contains the resolution time. I used the parameter **DROP = FALSE** to keep the dimensions so that I can apply the function RowMeans.

Unfortunately I am getting this error which I don't really understand what means:

```
Warning: Error in match.fun: 'rowMeans(tabla_tiempos[, 10, drop = FALSE])' is not a function, character or symbol
```

So as I said before I would like to aggregate by month and calculate the mean resolution time for every month and later to create another data frame (this would be **df_tresolucion**)containing all this information: 2 columns (month and mean time) and one row for each month.

Does anybody know how I could do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @PLapointe, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr`. Note that I removed factors from your data.frame and I forced tresolucion to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
tabla_tiempos%>%
  group_by(Metrica)%>%
  summarise(tresolucion=mean(tresolucion,na.rm=TRUE))

   Metrica tresolucion
     <chr>       <dbl>
1 apr 2017     1.73000
2 jun 2017    14.63500
3 may 2017    10.33333
```

**data**

```
Ticket <- c('119237','119239','120598','120600','120612', '120615')
Metrica <- c('apr 2017','may 2017', 'may 2017','may 2017','jun 2017','jun 2017')
Pais <- c('ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP','ESP')
Estado <- c('Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed', 'Closed')
Escalado <- c('CEDEX', 'CEDEX', 'TAC','CEDEX','CEDEX','TAC')
Vendor <- c('Cisco','Cisco','Cisco','Juniper','Cisco','Cisco')
Familia <- c('C7600','C7600','MX960','C7600','C7600','MX960')
Severidad <- c('Minor','Minor','Major','Minor','Minor','Major')
SLA <- c('Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA','Dentro de SLA')
tresolucion <- as.numeric(c('1.73','2.30','26.97','1.73','2.30','26.97'))
tabla_tiempos <- data.frame(Ticket,Metrica,Pais,Estado,Vendor,Familia,Severidad,SLA,tresolucion,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```